# Expected Value / Econometrics

Tags: econometrics, statistics

I would like to learn how the expression below is 1. Without understanding it I am having trouble to go on with Chebbyshev's Inequality. It's maybe too basic, but I appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$E\left[\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}\right] $$

$\sigma^2$ is a constant,

$$\frac{1}{\sigma^2}E\left[(y-\mu)^2\right] $$

I assume $\sigma^2$ is notation for the variance of $y$, and thus $Var(y) = \sigma^2 = E\left[(y-\mu)^2\right]$.

We now have,

$$\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sigma^2 =1 $$

Comment: Thank you very much for this fast reply and solution :)

Comment: @Sera if you found this answer useful, I suggest you to accept it (i.e. to click on the checkmark.)